# ASP.NET OutputCache - Where will the Cache be stored id Location="Any"

Tags: asp.net, location, outputcache, any

I want to use ASP.NET Output cache in my website. If i select Location="Any" where will the cache be stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output cache can be located on the browser client (where the request originated), on a proxy server (or any other server) participating in the request, or on the server where the request was processed.

for more information you can refere to the following link:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)